# multiple query not running

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I'm trying to run a query on my table to create a row and get it's auto incremented 'id' number to then be attached to associated records. I am sending the query using php and have tested it on my local WAMP host and my remote host. This is my code:

```
$myemail = someEmailAddress

$q = mysqli_query($cxn,"INSERT INTO `purchases`(`id`, `email`) 
VALUES (NULL , '$myemail'); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();") or die(mysql_error());
```

If I take out this bit:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The query runs fine and I get a shiny new record with a correctly auto incremented 'id' but put it back in and nothing happens at all. Incidentally, running the same query in the SQL window of phpMyAdmin for my WAMP server I get the result I was looking for.

I think the problem is in running multiple queries in the same string. As far as I can see the syntax is correct so is it a problem with the server I am running?

Let me explain what I want to achieve. I am going into business for myself and I want customers to be able to make bookings online. I want to group individual events that a customer might want to book at the same time, into a single invoice. I have an array ($_SESSION[basket]) collecting the data in the session and at the point of booking I want to create a new record in my 'purchases' table which has an auto increment primary key 'id', when that is created i need to know the 'id' value for that new record so I can link the event they are booking to the purchase through a third table with a many-to-many relationship.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not just do a second query to get the last insert id instead of trying to shove it all into 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the auto generated id off the last sql use this:

```
    The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a

 column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE

 statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute

, this function will return zero.
```

just call `$mysqli->insert_id` after the query when you need it.

sorry as you are using procedural style you will call it like this

`mysqli_insert_id($cxn)`

Comment: This appears to work perfectly for what I want to achieve but can you tell if this connection specific? In other words if by some fluke there were 2 people placing a booking a fraction of a second apart, could the query to create both of their purchase numbers run before the 1st person's purchase number is received by php causing both the `mysqli_insert_id($cxn)` procedures to return the same result, or will it only return the last id created by that connection regardless of other activity on the table? If so then that completely solves my problem and thank you very much!

Comment: @user1978206   it is for the last query of the specific connection. if what you are asking is that, if two people are querying at the same time, can it mix up the returned ids. the answer is no it cannot. and also if this worked for you, please accept my answer.

Answer (score -1):

use this function

```
function get_last_id()
{
    $q_last = mysql_query("SELECT max(id) as 'id' FROM purchases ") or die(mysql_error());
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch); 
}
```

Comment: Please describe what this function does for a complete answer.

Comment: Thought about that but could the table not theoretically be altered by another user between collecting the id and creating the next one? Unlikely, I know but I'd prefer to eliminate the possibility if I can. Thanks though